# Create drop down menu referring to the destination page

Tags: html

I would like to have the below mentioned pages in the drop down box.. Remember, all the texts are links and are referenced to diff pages..

Example: "Brazil Pull" - link 1
         (model)  - link 2
         (summary)  - link 3... etc...

A page already exists with these texts as links.. I need to create a drop down for them... How ?

Brazil Pull (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
Brazil Push Additional SKU rev (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
Brazil Push Newly Stocked Product rev (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)

Brazil Reprice (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
China Biology Phase 1 (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
China Chemistry Test (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
China Vetec (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
Japan Material Science Test (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
Mexico Vetec Test (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)
Singapore Chemistry Phase 1 (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)

Comment: Pretty much there are 2 questions you should ask yourself: 1. how to create a dropdown, 2. how to create page links. And I'm positive you can find both the answers on the first links if you use search.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2v993hy/). Using bootstrap as style js base.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Brazil Pull (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Brazil Push Additional SKU rev (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts) 3. 3. Brazil Push Newly Stocked Product rev (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Brazil Reprice (model) (orders) (summary) (contacts)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```